# Finding Voltage in a Circuit with a Capacitor

Tags: voltage, homework

[image: problem][image: my work so far]

I have applied the voltage division, but I am struggling to find a way to find a final answer, would I just distribute multiplication?

Thank you to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Use the Fourier transform, and inverse Fourier transform

Comment: @S.s is there any other way? I have not learned that yet

Comment: When you say "a way to get back to v" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @S.s I mean to get a final answer, am I able to distribute the 10e^(j0.2t)

Comment: Euler: \$e^{jx}=cos(x)+j\:sin(x)\$

Comment: @Chu giving her Euler was my first though too but from her answer's it is clear she is not in advanced class.  This is just a steady-state AC circuit problem she needs help navigating.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are stuck on our notation with the exponential.  This should help get you unstuck.

$$v(t)=10e^{j0.2t}=10cos(0.2t)$$

Since this is a steady-state, single frequency problem - you can replace that time based source with its [phasor](https://control.com/textbook/ac-electricity/phasors/) representation,

$$V=10\angle0°=10+j0 $$

**BACKGROUND**

If you calculate \$10e^{j\omega t}\$ as time t progresses you will see that you get complex values.  If you convert these complex values into [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor)  form you will see that you have a phasor of amplitude 10 that is rotating counterclockwise on the complex plane (x-axis is real, y-axis is imaginary). Here are a few terms if we let \$\omega=0.2 \$ radians (which is \$\frac{0.2}{2\pi}=0.032\$ Hz, so the rotating phasor will make 1 complete counterclockwise revolution in \$\frac{1}{0.032}=31.4\$ seconds.  In one quarter of that time it will cover 90° etc.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 \text{t (sec)} & \text{real} & \text{imaginary} & \text{angle} \\ \hline
\text{0} & 10 & 0 & 0° \\ \hline
\text{3.93} & 7.07 & 7.07 & 45° \\ \hline
\text{7.85} & 0 & 10 & 90° \\ \hline
\text{11.78} & -7.07 & 7.07 & 135° \\ \hline
\text{15.71} & -10 & 0 & 180°  \\ \hline
\text{19.64} & -7.07 & -7.07 & 225°  \\ \hline
\text{23.56} & 0 & -10 & 270°  \\ \hline
\text{27.49} & 7.07 & -7.07 & 315°  \\ \hline
\text{31.42} & 10 & 0 & 0°=360°  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

When plotted as time progresses it would look like this (from [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor)):

[image: from wikipedia page on phasor]

Comment: Anonymous - please explain the -1 so we can learn something.